# thread safe map for java

Tags: java

i need a thread safe map, i have something like this: (i'm very new to java)

```
 public static class Manager
        {
        static 
        {
//something wrong here, doesn't compile
           list = new java.util.Collections
          .synchronizedMap(new Map<String, Client>());
        }

       static Map<String,Client> list;

        public static void AddClient(Client client)
        {
        // thread safe add client to the list
        }

        public static void RemoveClient(Client client)
        {
        // thread safe remove client to the list
        }

        }
```

Comment: Note, mutable statics are a really, really, really bad idea.

Comment: A [simple](https://crunchify.com/hashmap-vs-concurrenthashmap-vs-synchronizedmap-how-a-hashmap-can-be-synchronized-in-java/) introduction to the topic...

Answer (score 107, accepted):

[`java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Comment: Moreover, this implementation is much fast than Collections.synchronizedMap or a locked HashMap

Answer (score 36):

The [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) class from the `java.util.concurrent` package is a thread-safe implementation of Map that offers far better concurrency than `synchronizedMap` (and far superior scalability over `Hashtable`). See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07233.html.

Comment: This is a better response of the accepted one for the presence of the interesting IBM link

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 9):

Use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your code should look like this, ignoring imports, et al.

```
public class Manager
{
    Map<String,Client> list = java.util.Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Client>());

    public void AddClient(Client client)
    {
        // thread safe add client to the list
    }

    public void RemoveClient(Client client)
    {
        // thread safe remove client to the list
    }
}
```

That said, beware that this is not as thread safe as you might hope. As others have mentioned, you probably want to use the [Java Concurrent Collections](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 2):

## Interfaces

Java bundles a pair of interfaces for a concurrent `Map`:

- [`ConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html)
- [`ConcurrentNavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentNavigableMap.html)

The first makes [thread-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) and [atomicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) guarantees. The second adds those guarantees to [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) implementations that keep their keys in a certain order.

## Classes

### Modifiable maps

Java provides two classes that implement those interfaces. Third-party libraries may also provide classes implementing those interfaces. The classes bundled with Java are:

- [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) (for `ConcurrentMap`)
- [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) (for `ConcurrentMap` and `ConcurrentNavigableMap`)

Example usage:

```java
ConcurrentMap < Project , Person > map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>() ;
```

…and:

```java
ConcurrentNavigableMap < Month , Person > map = new ConcurrentSkipListMap <>() ;
```

### Unmodifiable maps

If an [unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable) map works for you, see the `Map.of`, [`Map.ofEntries`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries(java.util.Map.Entry...)), and [`Map.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#copyOf(java.util.Map)) methods. Being unmodifiable brings thread-safe read-only access.

### Legacy map

There is a legacy class, [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Hashtable.html), that is generally not used anymore. But, for the sake of completeness, we should mention this class for its [synchronized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_concurrency#Synchronization) methods that provide thread-safety. To quote the JavaDoc:

> If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `HashMap` in place of `Hashtable`. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use `ConcurrentHashMap` in place of `Hashtable`.

## Table of `Map` classes

Here is a graphic table I made showing various characteristics of the various `Map` implementations bundled with Java 11.

Look for the red boxes in the *Concurrency* column.

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features]

Answer (score 1):

Your map "list" needs to be static if you want to access it in a static block.

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize an object member variable in a static block.  Static blocks are executed once when the class is first loaded, not once for every object of that class, whereas the variable "list" is created once for each object of the class.

Also, you can't instantiate a "new Map" because Map is an interface.  You need to wrap the synchronizedMap around a real Map like a HashMap or a TreeMap.

```
        {
           list = new java.util.Collections
          .synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Client>());
        }
```

Comment: i'm sorry, this is a static class, I shall update the question

Answer (score 1):

from java.util.concurrent

```
ConcurrentHashMap<K,V>
ConcurrentMap<K,V>
ConcurrentNavigableMap<K,V>
ConcurrentSkipListMap<K,V>
```

from java.util.Collections

```
Collections.synchronizedMap(Map<K,V> m)
Collections.synchronizedNavigableMap(NavigableMap<K,V> m)
Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(SortedMap<K,V> m)
```