# Java Unsafe Operations

Tags: java, vector, maps, unsafe

When compiling a short piece of java code I get a compilation note of having unsafe operations. I basically just was hoping for the concept of how to change my data structure that would make it safe.

The concept: I need to organize inputed strings into buckets based on their length, which could be arbitrary (although less than 80 chars).

The Code:

```
Map<Integer, List> buckets = new HashMap<Integer, List>();
            if(!buckets.containsKey(length))
            {
                buckets.put(length,new Vector<wordValues>());
            }
            //Now add the temp to the bucket
            buckets.get(length).add(new wordValues(temp));
```

And then I add the string to the list corresponding to its size.

What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792023/thread-safe-map-for-java

Comment: Why do `containsKey` AND `get`?

Answer (score 10):

You mix raw and Generics List, try:

```
Map<Integer, List<wordValues>> buckets = new HashMap<Integer, List<wordValues>>();
```

Also, usually class names start with upper case, e.g. `WordValues`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using the [*raw type*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) `List` rather than the parameterized [*generic type*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) `List<WordValues>`.
Generics are covered extensively in the Oracle [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

```
Map<Integer, List<WordValues>> buckets = new HashMap<>();
...
List<WordValues> values = buckets.get(length);
if (values == null) {
  values = buckets.put(length, new ArrayList<WordValues>());
}
values.add(new WordValues(temp));
```

Some tid-bits:

- `containsKey` and `get` both do identical look-ups. It seems kinda odd to do the it twice :-p
- Avoid using `Vector` in favor of `ArrayList`. If you need it to be synchronized, consider decorating it via [`Collections.synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29).

  ```
  Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<WordValues>())
  ```
- Java 7 supports type parameter inference which can significantly ease the burden on you. Notice above I didn't have to type `HashMap<Integer, List<WordValues>>`; instead, I merely typed `HashMap<>`, taking advantage of the new *diamond operator*.
- Avoid using class names that begin with a lower-case character; this is generally hard to read (and against the [Oracle Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html)). Consider naming your class `WordValues` rather than `wordValues`.