# Which Map class should I use?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

In http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html I see 19 classes that implement the Map interface.
Which one should I use? I want to map integers to integers. I would use Array but 
I see HashMap in many example, so I am thinking about:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> myMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
```

Basically I want to simulate the less strict arrays that I can find on other languages like PHP where I can asign any integer to any value without caring about fixed lengths or using lists.

Comment: Its way too broad.You have to choose the map according to your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *simplest* and most straightforward option is to use a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>()`. You don't have to worry about threading, or paying for any performance penalty whilst sorting (as you would with `TreeMap`) etc.

You also ask about threading. Note that HashMap itself isn't thread safe, and simultaneous operations on it will blow up (e.g. maps do internal state changes like resizing upon puts, and a simultaneous put will likely fail). So a `ConcurrentHashMap` will likely be required. However note that you may need to *still* synchronise around that object if you're performing multiple atomic operations e.g.

```
if (!map.contains(key)) {
   map.put(key, ...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not concerned about thread-safety, just use `Hashmap<Integer, Integer>`.   If multiple threads will be accessing the map, then [ConcurrentHashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) is probably your best choice.  See [thread safe map for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792023/thread-safe-map-for-java) for more details.

Comment: By "thread-safety", do you mean multithreading or something else? Yes, I do use multithreading.

Comment: Multithreading.  You don't need to use thread-safe hashmaps if multiple threads won't be accessing the map at the same time. If this is an issue, use concurrenthashmap.  I updated my answer with this info.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `HashMap` or `MultiHashMap`[ref from apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiHashMap.html), dependent on your project requirements. Synchronized collections from `Collections.synchronized*` are slower than normal collections. So basically if you will not use that collection in multithreading environment you should avoid synchronized collections for basuc one thread stuff because they are simply slower.

Comment: I do use it in multithreading environment, this is why I wanted to use  Collections.synchronizedMap() and also wrapping every code with synchronized(myMap){}. Is it correct? Is it much slower?

Comment: You can use `ConcurrentHashMap` if your map will be quite big because you can get better performance than `Collections.synchronizedMap` because `ConcurrentHashMap` is locked partially but another  `Collections.synchronizedMap` is locked on whole map. To reading http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/difference-between-concurrenthashmap.html

Comment: If my response was acceptable and suitable to your problem please accept it, thanks in advance!