# Thread safe map

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a some service that does some logic like logging, writing to db and calling some external service. It holds data in a map like `Map<Key, Data>` where Key - it's a Integer. When service gets data with key one put this data to the map, does some logic and after that returns updated data. The service should be concurrent and thread safe.

I have couple variants what it can be done. First it's make all methods synchronized(this or map) (but in this case I think it's a bad idea because the inner logic takes some time , and all another callers will be waiting). The second variant  it's make synchronization on the key. In this case I do lock  only a small segment, not all map.

Am I right about these two variants? Or maybe there are another variants?

Comment: Have you tried `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: Is it not sufficient? Google `"java concurrent collection"` and follow the first link to find more variants.

Comment: More important, *why* is `ConcurrentHashMap` not sufficient? If you have specific needs but don't tell us what they are, we can't help you.

Comment: That explanation of why you can not use `ConcurrentHashMap` makes no sense. It is *unclear what you are asking*.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792023/thread-safe-map-for-java

Comment: It seems that what you really want is a read-through cache. While you *can* implement this yourself, I recommend looking at [EHCache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/get-started/getting-started#read-through)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, MyClass>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) to store your data.

This data structure can safely be shared and updated between multiple threads.