# Multithreading for array in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

So, the scenario is like:

```
//Some code...

public Map<String, String> someFunction() {
    for (final UserDetail user : userDetailList) {
        // the following (below) code runs in background thread
        // long running task
        new RecordPersonalisedDao().getPendingRecordsForUid(user.getuId(), new RecordPersonalisedDao.OnResultFetched() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Result result) {
                // callback after the user is processed
                // put some parameter from result to map
                map.put(user.getName(), result.getTotal());
            }
        });
    }
    // return map only after all users are processed
    return map;
}
```

As mentioned in the comment of above piece of code, I want the final map to be returned only after the entire list of user is processed.

I cannot change the functionality of `RecordPersonalisedDao#getPendingRecordsForUid` so as to make it run in the main thread only.

How do I achieve this in java ?

Edit: This type of problem can be faced in general. So, I want to understand the solution for the same in java.

To put my question simply, I want behaviour like

- Run this code in background for all members in the array, and once it's done, send a callback.

(Roughly like)

```
[list_of_some_data]
    .forEach( run this function )
    .after(after the function is run in background for  all members of list - return some value)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [thread safe map for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792023/thread-safe-map-for-java)

Comment: Use join() method to wait until background thread is completed.

Comment: What you want is an ExecutorService and to use the Future that is returned by submitting a task as your callback.

Comment: If I understand correctly then you want to use `Future` and use `CompletableFuture.allOf` in order to wait for all the `Future`s. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36261808/3883957.

Answer (score 1):

Before the loop, create a `CountdownLatch` with a count equal to the user list length. Inside the result handler, count down after updating the map. After the loop`await()` the latch to be counted down, then return.

Comment: The real question is how to do things in parallel. I really don't see how your "answer" answers that. Don't get me wrong ... but I guess you didn't collect your 200K reputation by giving such answers, did you?

Comment: @GhostCat The question very clearly states that `getPendingRecordsForUid()` runs in a background thread, and that the question, more generally, is how to block until all background tasks have completed—under the constraint that you can't change the task itself.

Comment: E.g., "the following (below) code runs in background thread," "I cannot change the functionality of RecordPersonalisedDao#getPendingRecordsForUid so as to make it run in the main thread only," and "return map only after all users are processed"

Comment: Thank you Sir :) Used ``CountDownLatch`` to solve the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Map<String, String> someFunction() {
    CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(userDetailsList.size());
    for (final UserDetail user : userDetailList) {
        // the following (below) code runs in background thread
        // long running task
        new RecordPersonalisedDao().getPendingRecordsForUid(user.getuId(), new RecordPersonalisedDao.OnResultFetched() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Result result) {
                // callback after the user is processed
                // put some parameter from result to map
                map.put(user.getName(), result.getTotal());

                //We're done grabbing the results.. count down.
                cdl.countDown();
            }
        });
    }

    //Block this thread until all the results are in.
    cdl.await();

    return map;
}
```